# stringstream was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm having problem with stringstream.my visual studio nor linux g++ can understand stingstream. I've added sstream but it does'nt solve anything. I've worked with it before and really don't know what's up with it now?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SymbolTable.cpp"
#include "setjmp.h"
using namespace std;
jmp_buf *bfj;
int TOP , SP=3 ;
struct types{int int_val;float float_val;char char_val;bool bool_val;};

types DS[6400];
int main(){
...//some code here
label38 : stringstream s;
label39 : bfj = (jmp_buf *)"label65";
label40 : longjmp(*bfj,1);;
label41 : goto label43;
label42 : TOP=SP;
//some code here
}
```

I'm writing a compiler so the code is the output,that's why it may seams a bit odd.

Comment: This compiles for me. Are you getting any other errors or warnings? Are you sure you're using the C++ compiler (g++), and not the C compiler (gcc)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you include `#include <sstream>` then you must also reference the class by:

`std::stringstream` or declare `using namespace std;` before using it.

If you post more information we could provide more detailed help.

Comment: @angela: you already had that in the code snippet you posted though.

Answer (score 2):

This code compiles fine for me under G++:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "setjmp.h"
using namespace std;
jmp_buf *bfj;
int TOP , SP=3 ;
struct types{int int_val;float float_val;char char_val;bool bool_val;};

types DS[6400];
int main(){
label38 : stringstream s;
label39 : bfj = (jmp_buf *)"label65";
label40 : longjmp(*bfj,1);;
label41 : goto label43;
label42 : TOP=SP;
label43 : (void)0;
//some code here
}
```

The only difference is that I removed `#include "SymbolTable.cpp"`, and added a `label43`.

So apparently, if it doesn't work for you, the problem is in some of the code you omitted. The `//some code here` parts or in `SymbolTable.cpp`

Of course, it also seems *very* suspicious that you're including a cpp file. That is most likely an error.